# Yellow spark randomly shows up on my RPi2

Tags: power-supply

a yellow spark/lightning bolt randomly shows up on my screen. I think it means that the Pi is not getting enough amps from the PSU. My Pi also keeps rebooting randomly. I'm currently using a Microsoft phone charger to power my Pi, but I also have a better PSU that outputs 5.2V and 2 Amps. Can I use this PSU to power my Pi?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a traditional method to supply proper power to your Pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No! It **DOES NOT** mean you are getting insufficient current! The **voltage** is **too low**. You can have a PSU which can supply 12A, but if it can't do this at an adequate voltage you will have problems.

See [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Your phone charger may or may not be OK, but many chargers **DO NOT** provide 5V (they are designed to charge 3.6V batteries). Even for those that do, often the cables are often inadequate.

Answer (score 1):

That lightning bolt does indeed mean it isn't getting enough power. Make sure you use high quality PSU and cables. I myself bought an official samsung cable and a charger putting out a max of 2.5 Amps.

I am sure your 5.2V 2A PSU will work fine.